Indefinite Integral Of A Wave Packet
So, I have the following function (also known as a wave packet in physics):
$$5{e}^{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{25}} \cos(3x)$$
Now, I want to find the indefinite integral of this and I started with integration by parts:
$$\int 5{e}^{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{25}} \cos(3x) ~ dx = 5 \int {e}^{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{25}} \cos(3x) ~ dx$$
$$u = \cos(3x)$$
$$du = - 3 \sin(3x) ~ dx$$
$$dv = {e}^{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{25}}$$
$$v = \hspace{5pt} ?$$
I know that the integral of $\displaystyle {e}^{- {x}^{2}}$ is $\displaystyle \text{erf}(x) + c$ but how would the $\displaystyle 25$ work in the fraction? Also, I am guessing that I will have to do some kind of integral with the error function (because of the $\displaystyle v$), which, I don't really know how to approach.

You will have to write $\cos(3x)$ as a complex exponential then use the error function with imaginary arguments

$$I=5\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{25}}\cos(3x)dx$$
Writing $\cos(3x)$ as an exponential we get
$$5\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int(e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix})e^{-\frac{x^2}{25}}dx=\frac{5}{2}\left(\int e^{3ix-\frac{x^2}{25}}dx+\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{25}-3ix}dx\right)=\frac{5}{2}(I_1+I_2)$$
To solve $I_1$ complete the square at the exponent and substitute $u=\frac{2x-75i}{10}$ and $du=\frac{1}{5}dx$ and we get
$$I_1=
\frac{5e^{-\frac{225}{4}\sqrt{π}}}{2}\int\frac{2e^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{π}}du=\frac{5e^{-\frac{225}{4}\sqrt{π}}}{2}\operatorname{erf}(\frac{2x-75i}{10})+C_1$$
To solve $I_2$  We again complete the square on the exponent and substitute $u=\frac{2x+75i}{10}$ and $du=\frac{1}{5}dx$. And using our previous resault we get
$$I_2=\frac{5e^{-\frac{225}{4}}\sqrt{π}}{2}\operatorname{erf}(\frac{2x+75i}{10})+C_2$$
Therefore
$$I=\frac{25\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{225}{4}} \sqrt{\pi} \left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x + 75\mathrm{i}}{10}\right) + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x - 75\mathrm{i}}{10}\right)\right)}{4}+C$$

Making the problem more general
$$I=\int e^{-a x^2} \cos (b x)\,dx$$
$$x=\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}}\quad \text{and}\quad  c=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}} \quad\implies \quad I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int e^{-t^2} \cos (c t)\,dt $$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\, \Re \Bigg(\int e^{-t^2+i c t}\,dt\Bigg) $$  Complete the square and finish.
